# Bootstrap - Modal title not working properly in modal window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am having a career page which is responsible for displaying `model window` for each job that the person is willing to apply. Whenever the apply button is clicked the same `modal-title` is being displayed., that is being displayed for the first job. The following is he link of the [career page](http://careerpromag.herokuapp.com/). In the source code the `model-title` is displayed correctly, whereas while opening its not displaying the correct title. The following is the code of `modal-title`:

```
<div class="modal-title">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
     <h4>Apply for General Foreman (E&amp;I) position</h4>
</div>
.
.
.
<div class="modal-title">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
     <h4>Apply for Superintendent (E&amp;I) position</h4>
</div>
.
.
.
<div class="modal-title">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
     <h4>Apply for Sr. Yards Engineer (E&amp;I) position</h4>
</div>
.
.
.
```

For all the `model window` the first jobs `model-title` is being displayed. What might be the problem? Please help. I am new to Bootstrap.

Comment: You can't have more than one title for one model..You need to either change the id's or you need to dynamically change the title based on the button clicked, which I guess you can do using Jquery

Comment: @Navnit Okay, I will check that out. thanks

Comment: @Navnit It worked thanks...

Comment: Great...happy to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the href link that was calling the `modal-window` code. I was using the same name for calling all the `modal-window`. It worked fine while I gave different href names for calling different `modal-window`. I got this after the comment from @Navnit